# Dimension of the space of alternating n-linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant

Given a vector space $V$ with dimension $k$ over a field $F$, I have to show that the dimension of the space of alternating n-linear functions from V to F is $k \choose n$. How would I go about doing that? What important property of alternating multilinear maps do I have to consider?  I'm struggling to approach the problem.

Comment: If $k>n$ then how can we define this?

Comment: @MANI, if $k \geq n$ then the dimension is simply the binomial coeficiente $\binom{k}{n}$. If $k < n$ any alternating multilinear form $f(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})$ is evaluated at a linearly dependent sequence $(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})$, as a consequence $f(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) = 0$ for all $(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) \in V_{k} ^{n}$. That is to say, in the case $k < n$ we have that the space of all alternating multilinear forms is the trivial subspace $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V^{k}$ stand for the k-fold cartesian product of $V$. Suppose $V$ has dimension $n$ and a basis $e_1,\dots,e_n$ of $V$ and let $\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n$ be the corresponding dual basis of $V^{*}$.

The space of multilinear maps $V^{k} \to F$ has a basis elements of the form $\epsilon_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}(v_1,\ldots,v_k) = \epsilon_{i_{1}}(v_1)\ldots\epsilon_{i_{k}}(v_k)$ and thus has dimension $n^k$. The coordinates of a multilinear map with respect to this basis the values the map takes on a basis element.

The space of alternating multilinear maps is a subspace of this. All you need to do is work out how the additional information $A$ is alternating allows you to deduce what it's coordinates are without evaluating it on all of the basis vectors. You will find that you can deduce the coordinates by evaluating $A$ on $k \choose n$ basis vectors. Proving that the dimension of the space is $n \choose k$ is not too hard from this point.

As a hint, alternating multilinear maps are antisymmetric.

Comment: Could expand more on the hint?

Comment: I was thinking that alternating multilinear maps are equal to zero whenever any two adjacent arguments are equal to zero, not sure how that would help me evaluate the the coordinates of $A$.

Comment: You get the coordinates by evaluating $A$ on the basis vectors. For simplicity, if $A$ takes two arguments, then you know that $A(e_1,e_1)=A(e_2,e_2)=0$ for the basis vectors, so its $(1,1), (2,2)$ coordinate is always zero.

Comment: What you will say for dimension if $k<n$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $L^{n}(V_{k}, \mathbb{K})$ be the space of all $n$-multilinear forms. In [Dimension of vector space of multilinear form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117784/dimension-of-vector-space-of-multilinear-forms-vn-rightarrow-k/4435876#4435876) it is shown that $ \dim L^{n}(V_{k}, \mathbb{K}) = k^{n}$. Let $L_{a}^{n}(V_{k}, \mathbb{K})$ vector space of all alternating $n$-multilinear forms and let $f \in L^{n}_{a}(V_{k}, \mathbb{K})$. We claim that
$$\dim L^{n}_{a}(V_{k}, \mathbb{K}) = \binom{k}{n} = \frac{k!}{(k - n)! n!}.$$
To show that consider a basis $\{a_{1}, \dots, a_{k}\}$ of $V$, then we can write
$$
x_{j} = x_{1j}a_{1} + x_{2j} a_{2} + \dots + x_{kj}a_{k} = \sum_{i_{j} = 1}^{k} x_{i_{j} j} a_{i_{j}}.
$$
Then, by the linearity of $f$ at each component we have that
$$
f(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) = \sum_{i_{1}, \dots, i_{n} = 1}^{k} x_{i_{1}1} x_{i_{2}2} \dots x_{i_{n} n}f(a_{i_{1}}, \dots, a_{i_{n}}).
$$
Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote the set of all functions from $\{1, \dots, n\}$ to $\{1, \dots, k\}$. If $t \in \mathcal{F}$ is the function $t(j) = i_{j}$, let's write
$$
x_{t} := x_{t(1)1}x_{t(2)2} \dots x_{t(n)n}, \quad 
a_{t}:= (a_{t(1)}, \dots, a_{t(n)}).
$$
Hence, we can express $f$ as
$$
f = 
\sum_{t \in \mathcal{F}} x_{t}f(a_{t}).
$$
Since $f$ is an alternating multilinear form, then $f(a_{t}) = 0$ if $t$ is not inyective (in this case $f$ would have two equal components). Hence,
$$
f = \sum_{t \in \text{injec}(\mathcal{F})} x_{t} f(a_{t})
$$
where $\text{injec}(\mathcal{F})$ denotes the subset of all injective functions on $\mathcal{F}$ (there are $k!/(k-n)!$ functions on this set). Let $\mathcal{G}_{n}$ the set of all permutations of $\{1, \dots, n\}$, and let $\sigma \in \mathcal{G}_{n}$, then we define the function $\sigma f$ by
$$
\sigma f(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) = f(x_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, x_{\sigma(n)}).
$$
By definition, since $f$ is an alternating function, then $\sigma f = \text{sig}(\sigma)f$, where $\text{sig}(\sigma) = 1$ if $\sigma$ is an even permutation and $-1$ otherwise. Note that $t \circ \sigma \in \text{injec}(\mathcal{F})$ and
$$
f(a_{t \circ \sigma}) = \sigma f(a_{t}) = \text{sig}(\sigma) f(a_{t}).
$$
Now, consider the set $A_{n,k}$ of all increasing functions from $\{1, \dots, n\}$ to $\{1, \dots, k\}$ (there are $\binom{k}{n} = k!/[(k-n)!n!]$ elements in this set.). In addition, note that
$$
\text{injec}(\mathcal{F}) = 
\{t \circ \sigma : t \in A_{n, k}, \sigma \in \mathcal{G}_{n}\}.
$$
Then we can write
$$
f =
\sum_{t \in \text{injec}(\mathcal{F})}
f(a_{t})x_{t} =
\sum_{t \in A_{n,k}} 
\sum_{\sigma \in \mathcal{G}_{n}}
f(a_{t \circ \sigma}) x_{t \circ \sigma} = 
\sum_{t \in A_{n,k}} 
f(a_{t})
\left(
\sum_{\sigma \in \mathcal{G}_{n}}
\text{sig}(\sigma) x_{t \circ \sigma} 
\right)
$$
The final step is to show that
$$
v_{t}(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}) = 
\sum_{\sigma \in \mathcal{G}_{n}}
\text{sig}(\sigma) x_{t \circ \sigma} 
$$
is an alternating $n$-multilinear form for each $t \in A_{n, k}$ and that the set $\{v_{t}: t \in A_{n, k}\}$ is linearly independent and then it is basis of $L_{a}^{n}(V_{k}, \mathbb{K})$ with $\binom{k}{n}$ elements.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer!